# Suddenly, my chrome is loading every website linside iframe

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I do not know how does it happen. I can feel that everything is going inside iframe. Here is some example of my problem:

1. Every website, I browse, by right-clicking, I see:
   [this context menu about iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RGZj.png)
2. I myself is a web developer, so I know when the HTML entities behave weird, in every page, I can see the weird black border on `<select>` tag and `<input>` tags. [ss of the select menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxEYf.png)
3. Even my `document.cookie` is not being saved due to iframe behavior.

I posted on Google chrome support more than a month ago, there is no response still. Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried disabling browser extensions? Or simply run in incognito mode and see if the behavior persists.

Comment: Yes,, in the incognito mode, the behavior exists!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the future problem facers, the problem was from the Google Chrome 3rd party Theme that I used to use more than a couple of years. Since I used it for a very long time I could not take it as the perpetrator, but eventually, it was.